# Sorting rows and colums in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have this following matrix:

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] 
 [1,] 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351 
 [2,] 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562
 [3,] 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700 
 [4,] 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 
 [5,] 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039
```

I want to sort this matrix in order to make the following matrix.

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] 
 [1,] 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 
 [2,] 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700
 [3,] 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039 
 [4,] 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562
 [5,] 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351
```

Anyone got an elegant r-code?

Sincerely

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you wish to sort? Do you sort each column or all entries in an row-major order? Your given output is not unambiguous.

Comment: if your matrix is called dat, `dat[(order(dat[,1])), ]`

Comment: All your columns have same values?

Comment: dat[(order(dat[,1])), ] 

This code resolved my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not unambiguous. It depends on how you wish to sort. Do you sort each column independently? Or do you sort all values and arrange dem in a row-major fasion? Or do you sort all column after the order of the first?

```
# Read your data
x <- matrix(scan(text = "
2275.351 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351
2269.562 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562
1925.700 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700
1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195
1974.039 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039"), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 4)


# Sort all entries in a row-major order:
A <- matrix(sort(t(x)), nrow = nrow(x), byrow = TRUE)
print(A)

# Sort each column
B <- apply(x, 2, sort)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a[do.call(order, lapply(1:NCOL(a), function(i) a[, i])), ]
           V1       V2       V3       V4
[1,] 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195 1904.195
[2,] 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700 1925.700
[3,] 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039 1974.039
[4,] 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562 2269.562
[5,] 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351 2275.351
```